# Как ограничить выборку из базы?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Делаю выборку из базы. Есть две таблицы с товарами и товарными предложениями ( в одной товары , а в другой размеры и цены ).

У меня сейчас выводятся товары со всеми предложениями ( если есть 3 размера то выводится 3 одинаковых товара ) , а нужно только один.

```
    $this->db->select('products.id , pro_title, price , products.offline_store , products.trash, products_offers.barcode , photo_id , modified_date , dictionary.value');
    $this->db->from('products');
    $this->db->join( 'products_offers' , 'products.ind_id = products_offers.ind_id' );
    $this->db->join('dictionary' , 'products.brand = dictionary.id');
    $this->db->where('sale_a' , '1');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();

    return $result;
```

Подскажите как сделать нужный вывод. Спасибо.

Comment: сгрупируйте group_by()

Comment: Да, оно ) Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как написал splash58 нужно было сгруппировать group_by('products.id');

Comment: Добавте в ответ фрагмент рабочего кода.